# Why map2() in purrr doesn't work consistently?

Tags: r, purrr

I would like to add new column "date_seq" based on sequence of date between "check_in" & 1 day before "check_out". I use purrrr:map2(check_in, check_out, ~ seq(check_in, check_out - 1, 1)) as screen shot attached. I tried 2 methods but the method with pipe (2nd line) doesn't work as expected. What could be the reason? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using :

```
library(dplyr)

test_df %>%
  mutate(date = purrr::map2(check_in, check_out, ~ seq(.x, .y - 1, 'day'))) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(date) %>%
  select(-check_in, check_out)
```

Comment: ...oh, I miss the 'mutate' verb. my silly mistake. Anyway, you just help solve 2 problems at one go. TQ so much for your fast response.